# Entity Framework 5 many to many delete by dependent object

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-relationship, ef-database-first

I'm using Entity Framework 5 database first approach.

I have an existing database with these 3 tables: Person, Group, PersonGroup. This is to express a 1 to many relationship. A person can belong to multiple groups. The PersonGroup table has the IDs PersonId and GroupId.

Table structure:

Person: PersonId, PersonName

Group:  GroupId, GroupName

PersonGroup: PersonId, GroupId

[image: class diagram]

EF5 has added the PersonGroup table as a navigation property on the Person and Group entites. I want to remove a person from a group based on the group name. I still want to keep the person and the group.

How do I write this method in the repository? Here's what I have that doesn't work

```
public bool RemovePersonFromGroup(Guid personId, string groupName)
    {

        using (gblPersonEntities gblPerson = new gblPersonEntities())
        {
            var pg = gblPerson.Person
                .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault()
                .Group.Where(g => g.GroupName == groupName).FirstOrDefault();

           //doesn't work because pg returns as a Group entity and 
           //remove is expecting a Person entity and I just want to remove a 
           //PersonGroup entity
           gblPerson.Person.Remove(pg); 

            gblPerson.SaveChanges();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also in this project, all the entities are detached, don’t use proxy types and are designed to move between WCF service boundaries.

Comment: I don't understand your statement _EF5 has added the PersonGroup table as a navigation property_. It looks like you've got a many-to-many association (not 1-many) `Persons - Groups`, which would mean you can just remove a `Person` from a `Group`'s `Persons` collection. Only the junction record (`PersonGroup`) will be deleted. BTW do yourself (and us) a favor and pluralize collection property names.

Comment: When I said that "EF5 has added the PersonGroup table as a navigation property" it was because when I generated the model from the database EF5 added the PersonGroup table as a navigationproperty on the Person entity. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, can you show me the code to remove the junction record in PersonGroup?

Comment: Then I don't understand why you have `.FirstOrDefault().Group` (which is Person.Group). And what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Normally, EF would not make `PersonGroup` part of the class model. Can you show a class diagram?

Comment: I added the class diagram

Comment: I think your confusion can be traced to the fact that you're expecting a `PersonGroup` entity from which you should be able to remove objects. But as I said, it's not in the model. The navigation properties `Group.Person` and `Person.Group` are collections of persons and groups, respectively (so pluralize them to make it more consicuous). EF uses the junction table under the hood. Your `pg` variable is a `Group` that you can remove from the `Person`'s `Group` collection. (As in Slauma's answer that's spot-on as usual).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You load the person *including* its groups from the DB. Then you remove the group from the person's group collection (*not* from the context's group set (which would delete the whole group from the database)). Then you call `SaveChanges`. EF will recognize that you have removed a group from the original person's group collection and send a DELETE statement to the database that deletes the join record from the `PersonGroup` table:

```cs
public bool RemovePersonFromGroup(Guid personId, string groupName)
{
    using (gblPersonEntities gblPerson = new gblPersonEntities())
    {
        var person = gblPerson.Person
            .Include(p => p.Group)
            .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId)
            .SingleOrDefault()

        if (person != null)
        {
            var group = person.Group
                .Where(g => g.GroupName == groupName)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (group != null)
            {
                person.Group.Remove(group);
                gblPerson.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```